# KVMs not running after qemu-kvm upgrade in CentOS 8.1, RHEL 8.1

Tags: qemu, rhel, centos8, virsh

This is the error i encountered when i updated my CentOS 8.1/RHEL 8.1 machines and all the KVMs are showing the error below:

error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2020-06-09T12:41:10.410896Z qemu-kvm: -machine pc-q35-rhel8.1.0,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,smm=on,dump-guest-core=off: unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: The problem states the machine type Q35 is not well stated/configured in your virtual Kernel based machines RUNNING on RHEL 8/ CentOS 8

[Step 1:] cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/*.xml | grep \<name'\| machine'

This will list the machine type in all of the KVMs installed.

[Output Snippet]
machine pc-q35-rhel8.1.0

[Step 2:] cd /etc/libvirt/qemu; ll

This will list all the xml files in connection with your KVMs

[Step 3:] At /etc/libvirt/qemu Use virsh edit <KVM file> ###Don't include .xml###

Navigate to machine 

[Output Snippet]
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-rhel8.1.0'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' secure='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.secboot.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/Loadbalancer_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>

Change machine='pc-q35-rhel8.1.0' to machine='q35'
shift + zz to save and quit

[Step 4:]

systemctl restart libvirtd && systemctl status -l libvirtd
virsh list --all
virsh start --domain <KVM>
Check the status of your running KVMs
virsh list --state-running

Now the issue should be resolved and your KVMs should be humming away.
Note though if head back in and check on the configuration xml file with virsh edit, you'll note that q35 converts to pc-q35-rhel7.6.0 automatically.
But this shouldn't be an issue.
Cheers :)
```